# Accessing file in public folder without file extension

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I am trying to implement `apple-app-site-association` in my React app, which should be accessible at:

`<custom-domain>/apple-app-site-association`

It is a JSON file without an extension. When I place the file in the public folder when running a develop version it downloads the file (which is still wrong, it should open the json), but whenever I run a production version nothing happens.

I also tried adding to index html

```
<link rel="apple-app-site-association file" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/apple-app-site-association">
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I access the file when running a production build? I tried implementing this using React-router, but I couldn't find a proper way to do that there as well.

Thanks

EDIT: an example how it should look: https://facebook.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
It can be either in .well-known folder or root